# How to push data to json server and then display it in your html page in Angular/ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I am trying to make a dummy restaurant app using Angular/Ionic 1. I have created a modal to add comments and then i am pushing those comments to json server.
I am trying to display the newly added comment in the html page along with other comments already being there. 
The comment is getting pushed to json file but i am not able to display it on html page. After the modal gets closed, the page gets stuck.
How do i get to display the newly added comment?

modal html code as below:

```
    <ion-modal-view>
<ion-header-bar>
  <h1 class="title">Add Comments</h1>
   <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button button-stable button-clear"ng-click="closeComment()">Close</button>
    </div>
</ion-header-bar>

  <ion-content>
    <form id="addCommentForm" name="addCommentForm" ng-submit="submitComments()">
    <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input item-select">
            <span class="input-label">Rating</span>
            <select ng-model="mycomment.rating">
                <option ng-repeat="n in [1,2,3,4,5]" value="{{n}}">
                    {{n}}</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
             <span class="input-label">Name</span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="mycomment.author">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <span class="input-label">Comment</span>
            <textarea placeholder=""ng-model="mycomment.comment"></textarea>
        </label>
        <label class="item">
             <button class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit">Add Comment</button>
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
</ion-content>
```

Controller code as below:

```
     $scope.mycomment = {rating:5, comments:"", author:"", date:""};

           $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/dish-comment.html', {
              scope: $scope,
              animation: 'slide-in-up'
            }).then(function(modal) {
              $scope.addComment = modal;
            });
            $scope.openComment = function() {
              $scope.addComment.show();
              $scope.popover.hide();
            };

            $scope.closeComment = function() {
              $scope.addComment.hide();
            };


            $scope.submitComments = function () {

            $scope.mycomment.date = new Date().toISOString();
            console.log($scope.mycomment);

            $scope.dish.comments.push($scope.mycomment);
         menuFactory.getDishes().update({id:$scope.dish.id},$scope.dish);


            $scope.mycomment = {rating:5, comment:"", author:"", date:""};
            $scope.addComment.hide();
        }
            $scope.$watch('dish.comments', function() {
                $scope.test = $scope.dish.comments;
                console.log($scope.test);
                });
```

Below is the html page where i am trying to display the code

```
    <div class="card">
      <div class="item item-body item-text-wrap">
           <img class="full-image" ng-src="{{baseURL+dish.image}}" alt="Uthappizza">
            <h2>{{dish.name}}
             <span style="font-size:75%">{{dish.price | currency}}</span>
            <span class="badge badge-assertive">{{dish.label}}</span></h2>
            <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-offset-10">
               <h4>Customer Comments &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                   <small>Sort by: &nbsp;
                         <input type="text" ng-model="orderText">
                      </small></h4>
                <ul class="list">
                    <li ng-repeat="comment in dish.comments | orderBy:orderText">
                      <blockquote>
                         <p>{{comment.rating}} Stars</p>
                         <p>{{comment.comment}}</p>
                         <footer>{{comment.author}}, {{comment.date | date:'MMM. dd, yyyy'}}</footer>
                      </blockquote>
                    </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Below is my json file code, the last comment was newly added, but not showing in the html page.

```
     {
"id": 3,
"name": "ElaiCheese Cake",
"image": "images/elaicheesecake.png",
"category": "dessert",
"label": "",
"price": "2.99",
"description": "A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cake, with Graham cracker crust and spiced with Indian cardamoms",
"comments": [
  {
    "rating": 5,
    "comment": "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
    "author": "John Lemon",
    "date": "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
  },
  {
    "rating": 4,
    "comment": "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
    "author": "Paul McVites",
    "date": "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
  },
  {
    "rating": 3,
    "comment": "Eat it, just eat it!",
    "author": "Michael Jaikishan",
    "date": "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
  },
  {
    "rating": 4,
    "comment": "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
    "author": "Ringo Starry",
    "date": "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
  },
  {
    "rating": 2,
    "comment": "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
    "author": "25 Cent",
    "date": "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
  },
  {
    "rating": "3",
    "comments": "Wonderful",
    "author": "Henna",
    "date": "2017-01-12T11:20:04.825Z"
  }
]
```

}

Here is the recording of the app, i am trying to show that the screen freezes after the modal is closed with/without adding the comment

```
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lQhI.gif
```

Comment: Any error in the console ? Can you replicate this in a fiddle and share ?

Comment: i get the following error in the console after the page gets stuck- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). replicating in fiddle will be difficult, i have multiple files for this.

Comment: But my console.log displays the newly added comment. its not displaying on the html page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks nice except for one thing, you are saving your modal instance in `$scope.addComment` variable and then naming your form the same `name="addComment"`. In angular, the form is saved in a scope variable with it's name; so basically it's trying to save the form AND the modal in `$scope.addComment`.

You should change the modal's or the form's name and try again, because probably when you submit the form, it gets saved in `$scope.addComment` and steps the modal instance, then you can't use it to close the modal.

EDIT:
Apparently there is a known issue/unfixed bug with the ionic popover and the ionic modal. What you have to do is close the popover and don't open the modal until the next cycle. You can achive that with `$timeout` or, even better, using a promise:

```
$scope.openComment = function () {
    $scope.popover.hide().then(openModal);
};

function openModal(){
    $scope.addComment.show();
}
```

Comment: i changed the form name, still facing the same error. My page gets stuck after adding the comment.

Comment: I tried it and it's working great! Take a look: https://codepen.io/tinchomm/pen/apZBym . Did you close the ion-modal-view tag in your code? with </ion-modal-view>

Comment: Yes, i have closed the </ion-modal-view> tag. Its not working at my end. does that mean something wrong with json related files

Comment: What's different from the CodePen I sent you? I only commented the line with menuFactory.getDishes().update({id:$scope.dish.id},$scope.dish); because i don't have that service. Then probably that line is broking the code.

Comment: when i refresh the page, the comment get displayed. Its only when modal gets closed, the page gets stuck that time.

Comment: Since the CodePen is working perfectly with the code provided i can't help you further unless you share the whole code or create a fiddle or codepen yourself with the code.

Comment: hey i have uploaded the project on github, here is the link and i have created the readme file for information. https://github.com/hennasingh/Ionic-Project

Comment: I'm sorry it took me so long to answer you. I checked your code and solved the problem. Check the solution on the answer edit.

Comment: Great! I'm glad  :)

Answer (score 0):

So the page gets stuck with the oldest JSONS but doesn't display the newest data? If thats the problem you can make a `$watch` function to always watch the `$scope`, so that way you can alway be monitoring the latest inserted data.

Comment: I've made a example for you based on your code.
First, I've got the JSON data and made a `$scope.local`, and after that make a simple `$scope.$watch('local', function(){})` so it can watch whenever your JSON got changed (with insertion or deletion).
Here is the link that can show more [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/chrystiamjr/dhryada0/14/).

Comment: Also, I've found some erros in the `<ion-modal-view>` .
If you check your JSON you'll find that the last insertion came with a `comments` key instead of `comment`, it's due to `<textarea placeholder=""ng-model="mycomment.comments"></textarea>`, so you can change it to `<textarea placeholder=""ng-model="mycomment.comment"></textarea>`.

Comment: added $watch and replaced comments, still the same errors. I got two separate outputs for console.log inside $watch. one is undefined and and the other one is list of comments along with newly added comment. Something is going wrong somewhere..

Comment: Sorry for the wait.. In that case, in which part of the code the first undefined console.log occurs? And the second one with comments data?

Comment: Both on the same line, console log inside watch function